# Allow user to rate from 0.5 to 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made a rating component where user can rate but there is a problem. The user can rate from 0 to 4.5(0, 0.5, 1, 1.5 till 4.5) which is unexpected behavior, instead, I want the user to rate from 0.5 till 5. How do i make it so? Here is the component for star rating

Here is the workaround

https://codesandbox.io/s/9y14x3704

```js
class Rating extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rating: props.defaultRating || null,
      maxRating: props.maxRating || null,
      temp_rating: null
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.defaultRating !== this.props.defaultRating) {
      this.setState({
        rating: nextProps.defaultRating,
        maxRating: nextProps.maxRating
      });
    }
  }

  handleMouseover(rating) {
    this.setState(prev => ({
      rating: rating / 2,
      temp_rating: prev.rating
    }));
  }

  handleMouseout() {
    // this.state.rating = this.state.temp_rating;
    // this.setState({ rating: this.state.rating });
    this.setState(prev => ({
      rating: prev.temp_rating
    }));
  }

  rate(rating) {
    this.setState(
      {
        rating: rating / 2,
        temp_rating: rating / 2
      },
      () => this.props.handleRate(this.state.rating)
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { rating } = this.state;
    let stars = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
      let klass = "icon-star-o";
      if (this.state.rating >= i / 2 && this.state.rating !== null) {
        klass = "icon-star";
      }
      stars.push(
        <i
          style={{
            display: "inline-block",
            width: "10px",
            overflow: "hidden",
            direction: i % 2 === 0 ? "ltr" : "rtl"
          }}
          className={klass}
          key={i}
          onMouseOver={() => this.handleMouseover(i)}
          onClick={() => this.rate(i)}
          onMouseOut={() => this.handleMouseout()}
        />
      );
    }
    return <div className="rating">{stars}</div>;
  }
}

const props = {
  defaultRating: 2,
  maxRating: 5,
  handleRate: (...args) => {
    console.log(args)
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Rating {...props} />, document.querySelector('.content'))
```

```css
.rating{
  border: 1px solid gray
  padding: 5px;
}

i[class^='icon-star'] {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 10px;
}

.icon-star {
  background: gray;
}

.icon-star-o {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div class='content'></div>
```

Can anyone help me at this, please?

Comment: you can add 0.5

Comment: @milan, I have wrapped your code in a snippet. Please update it so that everyone can test it.

Comment: @Rajesh snippet does nothing ?

Comment: @Rajesh ohhhhhhh sorry - so you made it a snippet, but now we are waiting for milan to actually add some working code!?

Comment: @Zze I have update OP's code.

Comment: @milan, I guess setting `i` in for loop to start from 1 should do the trick. Please comment if otherwise

Comment: its not doing right

Comment: I will post the code on sandbox

Comment: @Rajesh Here it is https://codesandbox.io/s/9y14x3704

Comment: I did fix this by giving opacity: 0 to 10th star but I dont think that is the good way to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, [Have a look at updated codebox](https://codesandbox.io/s/p9zjzyvv40)

I've changed the count to be UNTIL 10 and reversed the stars

Here's the updated `render()` method:

```
  render() {
    const { rating } = this.state;
    let stars = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { /* note starting at one UNTIL 10 */
      let klass = "fa fa-star-o";
      if (rating >= i / 2 && rating !== null) {
        klass = "fa fa-star";
      }
      stars.push(
        <i
          style={{
            display: "inline-block",
            width: "8px",
            overflow: "hidden",
            direction: i % 2 ? "ltr" : "rtl" /* reverse the half stars */
          }}
          className={klass}
          key={i}
          onMouseOver={() => this.handleMouseover(i)}
          onClick={() => this.rate(i)}
          onMouseOut={() => this.handleMouseout()}
        />
      );
    }
    return <div className="rating">
    {stars}<br />
    {rating}
    </div>;
  }
```